# How can I add an icon into a binding without it deleting it?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, binding

I am trying to create a menu bar with drop downs and when clicked, it would show the drop down and also change the icon from a right arrow to a down arrow. However, Knockout JS keeps deleting the span tag inside the binding. How can I get around this?

This is my html:

```
<!-- Recursively traverse the nested structure -->
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'document_index_template', foreach: children}"><l><a href="#">Document Index</a></l></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="document_index_template">
    <li class="collapsible-child" >
        <a data-bind="text: label, click: function(){isExpanded(!isExpanded())}" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" ></span></a>

        <ul class="collapsible-child" data-bind='template: { name: "document_index_template", foreach: visibleChildren}'></ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
var document_type = 'loan';
var key = 'comparison';
define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko){

    var structureRequest = getStructure();
    structureRequest.then(function(data){
        window.treeNode = new TreeNode(data);
        ko.applyBindings(window.treeNode);
    });

    function TreeNode(data){
        var self = this;

        self.key = ko.observable(data.key);
        self.label = ko.observable(data.label);
        self.children = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.each(data.children, function(index, child){
            self.children.push(new TreeNode(child));
        });

        self.isExpanded = ko.observable(false);

        self.visibleChildren = ko.computed(function(){
            if(self.isExpanded()){
                return self.children();
            }else{
                return [];
            }
        });
    }

    function getStructure() {
        var url = "../structure/api/0?document_type=" + document_type + "&key=" + key;
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A `text` data-bind cleans the node and injects a text node. You'll have to move the text bind one level down:

```
<a data-bind="click: function(){ isExpanded(!isExpanded()) }" href="#">   
  <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></span>
</a>
```

For reference: here's a comment from the knockout source:

> We need there to be exactly one child: a text node. If there are no children, more than one, or if it's not a text node, we'll clear everything and create a single text node.

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js#L433